# How do I save results from a pass through query to a local table?

Tags: t-sql

I need to submit a series of queries to an Oracle server over ODBC from an MS SQL server and store the results as a table on the MS SQL server.

It has to be a pass through because the query requires a server side function defined on the Oracle server.
I can't save the table on the Oracle server and then access it via ODBC because of licensing restrictions from the vendor of the db running on Oracle.

Here's the code that returns the correct results, but I don't know how to save them:

```
DECLARE @BibID AS bigint

DECLARE BibList CURSOR FOR 
    SELECT BIB_ID FROM tblActiveSerialsThatHave740s
OPEN BibList 

FETCH NEXT FROM BibList INTO @BibID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
BEGIN
    EXECUTE 
    ('SELECT 
        AMDB.BIB_DATA.BIB_ID As BIB_ID, 
        AMDB.GetAllBibTag(AMDB.BIB_DATA.BIB_ID, ''740'', ''2'') As F740_All 
    FROM 
        AMDB.BIB_DATA 
    WHERE
        AMDB.BIB_DATA.BIB_ID = ' + @BibID + '
    GROUP BY BIB_ID '
    )
    AT REPORT
    FETCH NEXT FROM BibList INTO @BibID
END

DEALLOCATE BibList
```

Comment: Did you already try INSERT INTO ... EXECUTE?

Comment: I thought I'd tried that, but apparently not.
I added the INSERT INTO:
`    BEGIN`
`    INSERT INTO tblActiveSerials740s`
`     EXECUTE`
It gives me an error. Line 10 is the INSERT INTO:
Msg 8501, Level 16, State 3, Line 10
MSDTC on server 'MSSQL-DEV3\MSSQLDEV3' is unavailable.

Comment: I knew that was coming - you can either use the Distributed Transaction Coordinator or modify your linked server to not promote the local transaction to a distributed transaction: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008.aspx http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178532.aspx http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic861249-392-1.aspx

Comment: Very promising.  Now I just have to convince the DBA to let me change `N'remote proc transaction promotion'` to False.

Comment: Cade Roux, you were correct.  The DBA changed N'remote proc transaction promotion' to false and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.

Comment: Summarized all this in a proper answer so people realize it answered the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use INSERT INTO to capture the results of an EXECUTE.

Because you are executing a passthrough query, the Distributed Transaction Coordinator is going to come into play and you might need to ensure that a distributed transaction is not created (it's unlikely to be necessary to have a distributed transaction in your case) or that the Distributed Transaction Coordinator service is running:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2008/08/22/how-to-create-an-autonomous-transaction-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178532.aspx

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic861249-392-1.aspx